# Prototxt file not found:

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.1

any one clear this error because if i include in command line 
openposedemo.exe --face this error come
Error:
Prototxt file not found: models\face/pose_deploy.prototxt.
Possible causes:
        1. Not downloading the OpenPose trained models.
        2. Not running OpenPose from the same directory where the `model` folder is located.
        3. Using paths with spaces.

Comment: What happens when you fix the probable causes ?

Comment: openposedemo.exe to execute file in command prompt i got this error file not found:models\face/pose_deploy.prototxt.

Comment: Starting OpenPose demo...
Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.

Error:
Prototxt file not found: models\hand/pose_deploy.prototxt.
Possible causes:
        1. Not downloading the OpenPose trained models.
        2. Not running OpenPose from the same directory where the `model` folder is located.
        3. Using paths with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If running Windows tryIf running Windows 10 try opening an admin command prompt in your openpose root folder and then paste bin\OpenPoseDemo.exe.  You have to run it from the root context you cannot cd into the bin folder and then run it from there.

C:\openpose\bin\openposedemo.exe